# Directives messed up styling, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My goal is to create a navigation-item directive, that will work with Twitter Bootstrap. My current code places the `<li>` tags further down a level, so I presume that's the reason bootstrap's CSS is not compatible.

This is my directives.js file

```
angular.module('wdiary.directives', [])
 .directive('navitem', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'partials/directives/navitem.html',
        scope: {} ,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.redirectRoute = attrs.redirect;
            var r = attrs.redirect;
            scope.itemName = r.substring(r.indexOf('/') + 1, r.length);
        }
    }
 }]);
```

The navitem.html directive template:

```
<li ng-class = "{active: $route.current.activeNavigationItem == '{{itemName}}'}"><a href="{{ redirectRoute }}" ng-transclude> </a></li>
```

A part of index.html:

```
<div class="navbar" ng-controller = "NavigationController">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#/">WDiary</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <navitem redirect = "#/write"> Write </navitem>
      <navitem redirect = "#/list"> List </navitem>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

And the controllers.js file

```
angular.module('wdiary.controllers', [])    
.controller('NavigationController', ['$scope', '$route', function($scope, $route) {
    $scope.$route = $route;
}])
```

I have inspected the result, this is what I can see:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <navitem redirect="#/write" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope">
    <li ng-class="{active: $route.current.activeNavigationItem == 'write'}">
        <a href="#/write" ng-transclude=""> 
            <span class="ng-scope"> Write </span>
        </a>
    </li>
  </navitem>
</ul>
```

I think the solution would be to tell Angular not to wrap the list in another tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add in the replace: true to your return object in your directive. This will replace it like how you want.

```
angular.module('wdiary.directives', [])
 .directive('navitem', [function(){
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'partials/directives/navitem.html',
        scope: {} ,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.redirectRoute = attrs.redirect;
            var r = attrs.redirect;
            scope.itemName = r.substring(r.indexOf('/') + 1, r.length);
        }
    }
 }]);
```

Comment: So simple, yet so powerful. Thank you!