# AngularJS Directive muddles with CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an input form that I'm trying to add text tags to it (https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/jquery-textext) are the tags I'm adding. I've added a directive in to add the behavior:

```
angular.module('tags', [])

.directive('tags', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ngModel){
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(value){
                if (value){
                    console.log("value changed, new value is: " + value);
                    el.val(value);
                }
            });
            el.textext({
                plugins: 'tags',

            });
        }
    };
});
```

However, in the input form itself, Ive tried adding a bootstrap form class to the input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" tags ng-model="extraTags">
```

And as soon as I add the class form-control, the input shrinks to size 0 and I can't even see it. I've tested this out with other css added for classes, and it seems that the directive erases everything and makes it a normal input form, or worse, a non-existent, super small input form. I know angular runs through the items on the page and then modifies them, and I'm thinking this happens after the css has been added.

This answer doesn't work: [Directives messed up styling, AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154299/directives-messed-up-styling-angularjs) by adding a replace: true

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It probably is not angular (it wont just remove classes or anything) it is your plugin, `el.texttext` did you try commenting out that part and see if it still shrinks?